# Linux IO priority - fifo order? ...or?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, posix

Suppose two processes (or threads) both call `write` on a pipe/socket/terminal whose buffer is full, thus blocking. Is there any guarantee as to who gets to write first when buffer space becomes available? Is it FIFO order? Globally, or within a given priority level, and ordered first by priority? Or is it completely random/indeterminate?

What about starved reads? Will the first to call `read` get the data when it becomes available?

I'm asking specifically on Linux and as far as I know POSIX has nothing to say about these issues, but I'd also be interested if I'm wrong on that and POSIX does mandate particular behaviors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the kernel, the [`pipe_wait()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/fs/pipe.c#L90) function is used by both pipe readers and writers to block.  This function uses the [`DEFINE_WAIT()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/include/linux/wait.h#L599) macro to define a wait queue, which sets the `.flags` member of the wait queue to zero.

They are woken up with a call to [`wake_up_interruptible_sync_poll()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/include/linux/wait.h#L189), which calls down to [`__wake_up_common()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/kernel/sched.c#L4466).  You can see that if the `.flags` member does not have the `WQ_FLAG_EXCLUSIVE` bit set (as in this case), then *all* waiters are unceremoniously made runnable.

The scheduler will then use its normal heuristics to pick the runnable processes to run next.  In particular, a later waiter with a higher priority will get to go first - but note that if you have more than one processor core available, multiple waiters can start to run simultaneously, and which one actually gets to touch the pipe first depends entirely on which one manages to grab the pipe lock first.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**

Higher priority processes will likely get it first, but applications should not make assumptions on this behavior.

**Additional info:**

When data is available on a pipe/socket, a race condition can occur, in which a seemingly random process can grab the lock first. In *general*, higher priority processes will get the lock first, but this should *not* be depended on, as many other factors can contribute to this, such as the number of processor cores and active threads.

In general, user-level apps can assume that higher priority will ensure more frequent I/O access, but should not expect or assume consistent behavior defined beyond these generalities.

Comment: Isn't that just the default scheduler?  Or did they remove the Kconfig options?

Comment: You are correct, it is the default, but there are other options, which really goes to prove the point; user apps cannot depend on specific scheduling characteristics beyond generalizations.